# Higher order functions / closure in Javascript

Tags: javascript, closures, higher-order-functions

In the example below, I was wondering what the difference would be between greet('Hello') and greet('Hello')(). I logged both to the console and greet('Hello') showed Hello undefined but greet('Hello')() showed undefined. I didn't understand why that was happening. I'm confused on if the inner function is being invoked in greet('Hello') situation although () is not explicitly written there, it seems that since greet('Hello') is equal to function (name), this function is being invoked without (). With this reasoning, I'm not sure why greet('Hello')() is showing undefined. Wouldn't this just be passing in an undefined value and should therefore have the same result as greet('Hello') which was Hello undefined, not undefined?

```
const greet = function (greeting) {
  return function (name) {
  console.log(`${greeting} ${name}`);
  }
}

greet('Hello')('Jonas');

greet('Hello')

greet('Hello')()

Hello Jonas

Hello undefined

undefined
```

Comment: The output you've mentioned is not what happens, `greet('Hello')` will not log anything to the console and `greet('Hello')()` will log `Hello undefined`.

Comment: JavaScript does not have implicit invocation.

Comment: To understand the code better, instead of calling `greet('Hello')()` do it like this: `const sayHelloTo = greet('Hello')` then do `sayHelloTo()`. Since you are saying hello to nobody javascript will say `"Hello undefined"`

Answer (score 1):

The `greet` function returns a new function that doesn't return anything but logs an output.

Once you call the `greet("Hello")` It'll return a function equivalent to

```js
function(name) {
 console.log(`Hello ${name}`)
}
```

The following function does not return **anything**. The return value would still be undefined even if the `name` argument is present.

```js
const greet = function (greeting) {
  return function (name) {
    console.log(`${greeting} ${name}`);  // at execution of line 9: Hello undefined
  }                                      // at execution of line 10: Hello World!
}


console.log(greet("Hello"));   // function greet(name) {...
console.log(greet("Hello")()); // undefined
console.log(greet("Hello")("World!")); // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

The last output can be ignored because it is the return value of `greet('Hello')()`.

Since `greet('Hello');` is a no-op (like `123;` or similarly `"use strict";`), it all makes sense with 2 lines of output and the return value shown by the Browser.